# TypeError: "login is not a constructor" in login.controller.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a login model to MongoDB database using POST request.

But it throwing this error:

> TypeError: login is not a constructor in login.controller.js

**//////////////////////////////////////**

**My development environment:**

- macOS
- mongoose 4.11.0
- express 4.15.3
- node 9.5.0

**//////////////////////////////////////**

**Model file: `login.model.js`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{

 loginid: String,

 name:
 {
   type: String,
   required: true
 },

});

const login = module.exports = mongoose.model('login', loginSchema );


addLogin = (newLogin, callback) =>

{

  newLogin.save(callback);

}
```

exports = module.exports = {addLogin};

**///////////////////////////////////////////**

**Controller file: `login.controller.js`**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

var login = require('./login.model');


router.post('/', (req, res, next) =>

{

 var newLogin = new login({

 loginid: '12',

 name: req.body.name,

 });

login.addLogin(newLogin, (err, list) =>

{

if(err)

{

res.json({success: false, message: `Failed to create a new list. Error: ${err}`});

}
else

res.json({success:true, message: "Added successfully."});

});
```

Comment: Check do you correctly require files and path is correct.

Comment: Should be `require('./login.model')` if they are in the same folder

Comment: I'd edited the question: require('./login.model')

Comment: Can you please console.log(login) in the login.controller.js file after the require statement?

Answer (score 0):

I got to resolve by this by:

////////////////////////

Upgrade the mongoose to:

mongoose": "^5.0.10",

//////////////////////////////////////

Model file: login.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{

 loginid: String,

 name:
 {
   type: String,
   required: true
 },

});

var loginModel = module.exports = mongoose.model('login', loginSchema );


addLogin = (newLogin, callback) =>

{

  newLogin.save(callback);

}

exports = module.exports = {loginModel, addLogin};
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

Controller file: login.controller.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

var login = require('./login.model');


router.post('/', (req, res, next) =>

{

 var newLogin = new login.loginModel({

 loginid: '12',

 name: req.body.name,

 });

login.addLogin(newLogin, (err, list) =>

{

if(err)

{

res.json({success: false, message: `Failed to create a new list. Error: ${err}`});

}
else

res.json({success:true, message: "Added successfully."});

});
```